# Trouble using WSAssetPickerController

Tags: ios, xcode, image, picker

I'm trying to use a library in my project called [WSAssetPickerController](https://github.com/w5mith/WSAssetPickerController). It's a picker controller for iOS that enables you to select multiple pictures. I have followed the instructions strictly to include it in my project but I am getting the following error:

```
ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/davdon42/Documents/Apps/Photomosaic/Photo Mosaic/libWSAssetPicker.a, missing required architecture i386 in file /Users/davdon42/Documents/Apps/Photomosaic/Photo Mosaic/libWSAssetPicker.a (2 slices)
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_WSAssetPickerController", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in ImportImagesViewController.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

any ideas?

I think it may be something to do with versions of xcode and the iphone sdk. I'm using Xcode Version 4.5.1  and iOS SDK 6.0 targeting iOS 5.1.

Thanks

Comment: Have you double checked that you've added all required frameworks to the project?

Comment: yes, i have added all required frameworks

Answer (score 0):

user1775671,

The error is a result of the library not being compiled for the iOS simulator. I updated the project to compile the library for both the simulator and devices. The README is also updated with new instructions as follows:

1. Open the demo project
2. Select the `WSAssetPickerCombined` scheme
3. In the menu bar choose Product > Build
4. Copy the generated `WSAssetPicker` directory (found in the builds folder in the project directory) into your project.
5. Make sure that `libWSAssetPicker-Combined.a` has been added to your targets Build Phases

You could also get the code via [CocoaPods](http://cocoapods.org/) which is a pretty handy way to manage dependencies for your projects.